# looking for sound effect appearing in recent pokemon episode

Tags: sound-effects

I am looking for a sound effect used in the Pokemon episode Cloudy Fate Bright Future, it's like a strange zappy rish sound effect.

In the video, it appears from 0:40 to 0:43.
I know it's not unique to Pokeon because I've heard it on a few tv shows when I was in a hotel a few weeks ago.
anyway, can someone either link me to this sound effect (liek where to downlaod it) or show me where to go so i can get this sound myself?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to start trawling places like [freesound](http://www.freesound.org) or attempt to construct it yourself. You will need to be looking at things like ring modulators, noise and variable tone generators to get this right.